# cmake: library dependent on another library (sqlite3pp)

Tags: c++, sqlite, cmake, git-submodules

I am trying to link  with `cmake`  [`sqlite3pp`](https://github.com/iwongu/sqlite3pp) library to my application, which in turn depends on `sqlite`. So the dependency graph is following:

```
my_app  --> sqlite3pp  --> sqlite
```

A trick that works fine, but is too clumsy for distribution (I am using `git submodule`), is to put `sqlite` inside the `libs/sqlite3pp/src`:

```
project
|___ src    # my project
|___ libs   # libraries
|      |___ sqlite3pp
|      |        |___ src
|      |              |___sqlite   # I copy it here; clumsy  :-(
...    ...
```

With following line in the `sqlite3pp/src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sqlite3")
```

However, with `git submodule` it creates a big mess, as I need to modify the submodule. So I try to pull the directory `sqlite` two levels up, into `libs` directory:

```
project
|___ src    # my project
|___ libs   # libraries
|      |___ sqlite3pp
|               |___ src
|
|___ sqlite   # Now it looks better
...    ...
```

Now, two approaches I tried did not work (I am very new to `cmake`):

1) when I replace the above statement with

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../sqlite3")
```

The `cmake` does not recognise the relative path.

2) Trying to manage linking from the `project/CMakeLists.txt` file by following lines:

```
set(sqlite_path "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/sqlite")
include_directories(sqlite_path)
add_subdirectory( sqlite_path )
add_library(sqlite3 STATIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/sqlite/sqlite3.c")

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/sqlite3pp/src")
add_subdirectory("libs/sqlite3pp/src")


TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sqlite3pp "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/sqlite/sqlite3.c" )
target_include_directories( sqlite3pp PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/sqlite> )
```

leads to the situation when `cmake`  looks successful, but in `make` after successful compilation of both libraries, when linking them to the project, I receive a bunch of 'undefined reference' errors:

```
linking CXX executable ../../bin/myapp-1.0.0/myapp
../libs/sqlite3pp/src/libsqlite3pp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the linker errors use `Threads` package and `CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT` variable from it:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(libsqlite3pp ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

See [FindThreads](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindThreads.html) for details

Comment: magic! thank you!
Where can I read what 'the thread library of the system' means?